# formatting plotyy with two vectors for each y axis

Tags: matlab

I have a plotyy figure in MATLAB with 2 vectors in on each y axis.

`plotyy(x1,[y1(:),y2(:)], x1,[y3(:),y4(:)])`

I need to format each of the lines separately, but can not find the documentation about how to do this.  Can someone please me show an example?

Comment: Did you find my answer helpful? If so, feel free to mark the question answered. If not, please let me know why and I can attempt to improve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does the following example code help?

```
%# Generate some data
N = 20;
X = (1:N)';
Y1 = randn(N, 1);
Y2 = randn(N, 1);
Y3 = randn(N, 1) - 50;
Y4 = randn(N, 1) - 50;

%# Perform the plotyy, returning an axes handle, and a handle for both figures
[Axes, fig1, fig2] = plotyy(X, [Y1 Y2], X, [Y3 Y4]);

%# Change the format of Y1 and Y2 (separately)
set(fig1(1), 'LineStyle', ':');
set(fig1(2), 'LineStyle', '--');

%# Change the format of Y3
set(fig2(1), 'LineStyle', '-.');
```

In the above code, the figure handle `fig1` corresponds to the first y-plot, ie `Y1` and `Y2`, and I can access the individual lines by indexing `fig1` with `1` and `2`.

Similarly, the figure handle `fig2` corresponds to the second y-plot, ie `Y3` and `Y4`, and I access `Y3` by indexing this handle with `1`. I could also access `Y4` with `fig2(2)`, if I so desired.